# getting name of previous test step in SoapUI groovy script

Tags: groovy, automated-tests, soapui

I'm new to groovy scripting in SoapUI and a bit confused regarding the amount of information available, so I may just have overlooked the answer to this.

There is a method `context.getCurrentStep()` available in scripts which loaded the GroovyUtils. But in a script step this, of course, returns the name of the script step itself.

Now I want to access the name (more precisely the response) of the previous step without using it's name explicitly. Is there an easy method to acchieve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
def currentStepInd = context.currentStepIndex
def previousStep = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepAt(currentStepInd - 1)
log.info previousStep.name
```

More information is available in the [API JavaDocs](http://www.soapui.org/apidocs/index.html?com/eviware/soapui/model/testsuite/TestCase.html).

Answer (score -1):

You would want to do the following in your script:

```
def response = context.expand( '${previous_step_name#Response#}' )
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response, but, no, I don't want to do that. I want to avoid using the name of the previous step, this is clearly stated in my question and that's exactly the point of my question.

Comment: Referencing the step by a unique name is far better approach in practice, for much the same reason why we reference functions my name, not line number.